# upload all the extentions of allowed format

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, mime-types

hello all i am having a issue with my upload document by php
i have validated the upload file by php like

```
      function uploadanyfile($fileName){
$allowedExts = array("pdf","doc","docx","png","jpg","jpeg","gif","GIF","ppt","pptx","PNG","JPEG","JPG","psd","txt","xlsx","xls","rtf");$refrenext=explode(".", $_FILES["$fileName"]["name"]);
$extension = end($refrenext);
if ( (
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/pdf") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/acrobat") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/x-pdf") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/msword") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/rtf") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/psd") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/psd") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "text/plain") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "application/photoshop") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/photoshop") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/PJPEG") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/PNG") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/png") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/GIF") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/JPG") ||
($_FILES["$fileName"]["type"] == "image/jpg") ) &&
in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
  if ($_FILES["$fileName"]["error"] > 0)
  {
 $retuva= 'error in uploading may be the file type is not supported.!!';
  }
  else
 {
$retuva= 'Success1230';
  }
 } else {
 $retuva= 'file not uploaded !! Invalid file type.';
  }
 return $retuva;   
}
```

the function works good but the problem is that when i try to upload any ppt or doc of any other extention like pptx or csv etc the function says invalid file i know the reason but i can not list all the possible values of any perticular file a doc can have hundreds of extentions in mac or windows..

can i get a help where i can allow all the possible uploads only restrict the files which can harm my server lke .php or exe files... ?

Comment: invert the condition: check for forbidden extensions

Comment: can you modify the function and let me know the possible extensions of all harmfull extentions ..

Comment: Really, not. You can [google-it](http://www.google.com/search?q=upload+harmful+extensions) for that. BTW your original approach is better.